# Does anyone know how to change a div background color with a button click?

Tags: html, button, colors, background

When I click a button I want to change a background color of a div based on an if statement

Comment: Is there any code that you have tried?

Comment: Mmmm... The smell of homework

Comment: @pang I'm not experience really at all with coding so I'm just trying to learn. I'm making my own game and I want to know how to make it so that when I press a button, the game updates so that another div background color turns green to show that it is upgradable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="divs" style="background-color: green">
<p>Your Div</p>
</div> 
<input type="button" value="Click Me to change color" onclick="func()"></input>
</body>
<script>
function func(){
 document.getElementById("divs").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
</script>
</html>
```

You could have googled this.